# Reading Comprehension

Tags: traducción, uso-de-palabras

I just finished reading a rather long article about estafadores cibernéticos :

https://mundo.sputniknews.com/20210512/su-novio-de-tinder-le-estafo-83000-euros-los-ciberdelitos-en-espana-se-disparan-por-la-pandemia-1112104644.html

and feel that, given the context, this sentence :

Los correos electrónicos o mensajes de texto con links o publicidad donde se venden o promocionan mascarillas o material necesario para la pandemia están a la orden del día, y aunque parezca mentira, no son pocos los que se resisten a pinchar en el enlace que robará su intimidad.

is logically unsound in that los que se resisten should actually not be many.

Would you agree?

Comment: You're probably right. The sentence seems to have an extra "no". It should be "... parezca mentira, son pocos los que ..." but it looks just like a typo to me.

Comment: I interpret _no son pocos los que_ as meaning there are many people who cannot resist clicking.

Comment: @mdewey The point is that "resist" is in the affirmative: "...there are many (not few) who refuse to click" while it should be "there are many (not few) who cannot refuse to click".

Comment: @Gustavson I must have been reading what I thought the author meant to say, not what the words actually were.

Comment: I rather think that the sentence has one *no* too few. It should be *no son pocos los que no se resisten*. Of course, it can be written in a more straightforward way: *no son pocos los que acaban pinchando en el enlace...*

Answer (score 1):

"No son pocos los que se resisten" means that there "are many who resist" because you are denying that there are few. And I'm sure this isn't what you wanna say. I think that you wanna say that only few resist, so it could be "son pocos los que se resisten" or "no son muchos los que se resisten".